# How can I prevent Spyne from adding a xml-namespace import whenever I import its package?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, spyne

I have defined a simple SOAP-service in Spyne.

When I run my server like using the run module functionality of python like this:

```
python -m my_module.service
```

then everything's fine.

But when I run it from a wrapper script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import my_module.service
sys.exit(my_module.service.main())
```

then suddenly in the generated WSDL, there will exist a namespace import `xmlns:s0="my_module.service"` on the`<wsdl:definitions …>`-tag.

Why is that? Where is that coming from? How can I set this myself in the main() method or prevent it from getting inserted in the first place? I looked throught he code of spyne but couldnt find the relevant lines.

Answer (score 0):

This thread at GitHub explains how and why:
https://github.com/arskom/spyne/issues/233